# Why does jquery addClass and removeClass work properly only with alert function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my own slider with jquery. Following is the working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(".carousel-indicators li").click(function(){
   $(".carousel-indicators li").css("background-color", "transparent");
   $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  });


  var active1, prev1, next1;
  
  function rotateimages(){
   active1 = $(".item.active");

   if(active1.prev().length == 0) {
    prev1 = $(".item").last();
    prev1.removeClass("mytrans");
    prev1.addClass("prev");    
   }
   else {
    prev1 = active1.prev();
    prev1.removeClass("mytrans");
    prev1.addClass("prev");    
   }

   if(active1.next().length == 0) {
    next1 = $(".item").first();
    next1.removeClass("mytrans");
    next1.addClass("next");  
    //alert();      
   }
   else {
    next1 = active1.next();
    next1.removeClass("mytrans");
    next1.addClass("next"); 
    //alert();
   }
   

   active1.removeClass("active").addClass("prev mytrans");
   next1.removeClass("next").addClass("mytrans active");   
   prev1.removeClass("prev mytrans");

  }

  setInterval(rotateimages, 3000);

 });
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
 }
 .container {
  width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 100%;
 }
 #myCarousel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 45%;
 }
 .carousel-indicators li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .mytrans {
  transition: all 1s;
 }
 .carousel-inner .item {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
 }
 .carousel-inner .item.prev {
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
 }
 .carousel-inner .item.next {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
 }
 .carousel-inner .item.active {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
 }
 .carousel-inner .left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
 }
 .carousel-inner .right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://madaboutwords.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/one.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/gb/number-three-22.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/gb/number-four-10.gif" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I designed the code to put the `next` image to the right of the container and then move it smoothly to reach the center. But the `next` image never reaches `left: 100%`. However if I add an `alert()` after the jquery addClass method the `next` image reaches the right of the container. Following is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".carousel-indicators li").click(function() {
    $(".carousel-indicators li").css("background-color", "transparent");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  });


  var active1, prev1, next1;

  function rotateimages() {
    active1 = $(".item.active");

    if (active1.prev().length == 0) {
      prev1 = $(".item").last();
      prev1.removeClass("mytrans");
      prev1.addClass("prev");
    } else {
      prev1 = active1.prev();
      prev1.removeClass("mytrans");
      prev1.addClass("prev");
    }

    if (active1.next().length == 0) {
      next1 = $(".item").first();
      next1.removeClass("mytrans");
      next1.addClass("next");
      alert();
    } else {
      next1 = active1.next();
      next1.removeClass("mytrans");
      next1.addClass("next");
      alert();
    }


    active1.removeClass("active").addClass("prev mytrans");


    next1.removeClass("next").addClass("mytransactive");


    prev1.removeClass("prev mytrans");

  }

  setInterval(rotateimages, 3000);
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.container {
  width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
#myCarousel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 45%;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mytrans {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.carousel-inner .item {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.carousel-inner .item.prev {
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner .item.next {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner .item.active {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner .left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
}
.carousel-inner .right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://madaboutwords.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/one.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/gb/number-three-22.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/gb/number-four-10.gif" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem seems to be that the class `next` is being added and removed too fast. So it may be possible that the before the styles of `next` are added the class `next` is removed. The code snippet is:

```
else {
    next1 = active1.next();
    next1.removeClass("mytrans");
    next1.addClass("next"); 
    //alert();
}


active1.removeClass("active").addClass("prev mytrans");
next1.removeClass("next").addClass("mytrans active");           
prev1.removeClass("prev mytrans");
```

**Question:** How do I apply the styles of `next` class before the `next` class is removed by the removeClass function?

Comment: That is because the statements outside `if..else` won't *necessarily* execute after those inside the block. So in short the `next1.removeClass("next")` should ideally execute after the `next1.addClass("next");` from the `else{}`. Use a `setTimeout()` to handle this.

Comment: @ShaunakD How can a statement written after an `if..else` execute before the `if..else` statement?

Comment: I did not say they execute before. The time lag between these is negligible which might be causing the problem with `add/removeClass()`

Comment: @ShaunakD So is my guess correct that remove class executes before addClass  could actually add the class?

Comment: @ShaunakD What should be the time delay for `setTimeout()`? I used `1ms` first but that suddnly works good and then suddenly start working incorrectly. Now I am using `10ms`.

Comment: Im not sure about the interval `addClass()` takes to reflect. Try with 100ms or 200ms that is still minimal.

Comment: @ShaunakD So much delay could be problematic if my slide change in every half second. How do professional sliders like that of bootstrap work? If instead of using classes I use inline styles with `css()` method?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using the removeClass/addClass functions like this.

The most elegant way in jQuery is to toggle them like such:

```
active1.toggleClass('active');
active1.toggleClass('prev mytrans');
next1.toggleClass('next');
next1.toggleClass('mytrans active');
```

Using this method you can create a function like such, which is easier to maintain and doesn't clutter the code as much as seperated add/removes:

```
function toggleNext(){
    active1.toggleClass('active');
    active1.toggleClass('prev mytrans');
    next1.toggleClass('next');
    next1.toggleClass('mytrans active');
}
```

Also one of the downsides of removing/adding classes is that when jQuery can't find find class to remove/add, your code will seize working.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: But why doesn't add/remove class work without alert function?

Comment: @user31782 it probably works, but throws an exception. Check your browser's console to see what exception is being thrown and share it here please. The only thing the `alert` does is temporarily suspend your code until the `alert dialog` is dismissed.

Comment: I do not get any exception in the console.

Comment: That probably has to do as I said before, with the fact that the alert PAUSES the execution of code, giving the document time to load in the actual body. Try using the holdReady method jQuery provides. See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/

Comment: toggleClass also works the same as add/removeClass. Is using setTimeout the only way out? I couldn't use holdready function too. Documentation says I should use holdeady before document ready because _calling this method after the ready event has already fired will have no effect._

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $(".carousel-indicators li").click(function () {
                $(".carousel-indicators li").css("background-color", "transparent");
                $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
            });


            var active1, prev1, next1;

            function rotateimages() {
                active1 = $(".item.active");

                if (active1.prev().length == 0) {
                    prev1 = $(".item").last();
                    prev1.removeClass("mytrans ").addClass(" prev");
                } else {
                    prev1 = active1.prev();
                    prev1.removeClass("mytrans ").addClass(" prev");
                }

                if (active1.next().length == 0) {
                    next1 = $(".item").first();
                    next1.removeClass("mytrans ").addClass(" next");
                    //alert();                      
                } else {
                    next1 = active1.next();
                    next1.removeClass("mytrans ").addClass(" next");
                    //alert();
                }


                active1.removeClass("active").addClass("prev mytrans");


                next1.removeClass("next").addClass("mytrans active");


                prev1.removeClass("prev mytrans");

            }

            setInterval(rotateimages, 3000);
        });


    </script>
    <style>

        .carousel-inner > .item > img,
        .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .container {
            width: 768px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0 15px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #myCarousel {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: lightgray;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .carousel-indicators {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 45%;
        }
        .carousel-indicators li {
            list-style-type: circle;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .mytrans {
            transition: all 1s;
        }
        .carousel-inner .item {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
        }
        .carousel-inner .item.prev {
            left: -100%;
            top: 0;
            display: block;
        }
        .carousel-inner .item.next {
            left: 100%;
            top: 0;
            display: block;
        }
        .carousel-inner .item.active {
            left: 0%;
            top: 0;
            display: block;
        }
        .carousel-inner .left {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
            top: 50%;
        }
        .carousel-inner .right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10%;
            top: 50%;
        }


    </style>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://madaboutwords.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/one.png" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Chania</h3>
                        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://digimind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/number2c.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Flowers</h3>
                        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/gb/number-three-22.png" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Flowers</h3>
                        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/gb/number-four-10.gif" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Flowers</h3>
                        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Try this code. Tested

Comment: It is not working as supposed to be. THe images must come from the right of the container.